# MySQL Server does not start after changing max_allowed_packet parameter

Tags: mysql, max-allowed-packet

**MySQL Community Edition 8.0.13 on Windows 10 Pro 32 GB x64**

I am running the community server 8.0.18 (from the command line and not the service) and I need to set the max_allowed_packet value to higher than the default.

However,the server hangs on start with max_allowed_packet=16M, both when

- change is made in the ini file, or
- the value is passed as a command line parameter

***Update***:It seemed strange that the server would not start after a legal change - so I just saved the conf (my.ini) file without making any changes. And the got the same result

The ini file is as follows:

```
# The maximum size of one packet or any generated or intermediate string, or any parameter sent by the
# mysql_stmt_send_long_data() C API function.
max_allowed_packet=16M
```

The steps I followed are:

1. Install MySQL with advance logging and turn on all logs and without setting up a service
2. Start server by running mysqld : starts ok
3. Stop server by running mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown : shutsdown ok
4. change the value in the my.ini
5. Start server - server hangs

Full logging is on but nothing even gets written to the log. The last entry in the log is:

```
2019-10-24T14:47:56.916731Z    10 Connect   root@localhost on  using SSL/TLS
2019-10-24T14:47:56.916973Z    10 Query shutdown
2019-10-24T14:47:56.917224Z    10 Query
```

At this point, the only thing possible is to reboot, uninstall and then install again.

I have searched the forum for similar issues, and none of the previous suggestions apply/or work.

Comment: Anything in the log around the time you made the `max_allowed_packet=16M` change? I'm asking because this happened to me just yesterday and it was because I used a deprecated configuration change.

Comment: What are a few lines above `max_allowed_packet=16M`? `[mysqld]` or `[client]`, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

Issues resolved: Am posting an answer instead of deleting the question just in case it helps somebody else.

I had the conf (ini) file open in an editor (sublime/atom at different times) while I was starting the server. Finally I used notepad edited the file, closed it and the server started just fine.

I think the server is not able to load the conf file if it is open by another process.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I stumbled onto this while researching the same problem, but a different cause: In Windows, if you're using Notepad to edit your my.ini file, it can change the file encoding from ANSI to Unicode.  Re-open the my.ini file and File>SaveAs and verify the encoding option is "ANSI."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).